# Updating javascript array with click when new mysql data comes in

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using the following code to send mysql database content into a javascript array. This works fine when I start the page, but when the database gets a new entry, the new entries are not added to the array when I rerun this bit of code - unless I reload the entire page.

```
<p><button onclick="save_image()">Send image</button></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function save_image(){
   var userName = 
   <?php 
      $conn = new mysqli(.........."); //connect to database
      $d = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM canvas_data" );
      $usernames = array();
      while( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($d) ) {
         $usernames[] = $r['name'];
      }
      echo json_encode( $usernames );
   ?>;
   console.log(userName)
}
</script>
```

I realize there are other pages about this topic, but I didn't know how to apply them to my case. If you have some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: new Entries in sense, this depends upon where you insert your canvas_data, and where you are calling the above piece of code.

Comment: You need ajax to get new data from database.

Comment: I added the complete relevant code. And I read before that Ajax can do the trick, but I have no idea how. I used some get function to get the array from the database, but with the same result.

Comment: JavaScript cannot execute PHP. What your code above will do is to take the output from the PHP code and place it exactly where your `<?php` starts. Once the page is loaded, the PHP code will not exist there any longer. In order to retrieve data from your server, you will need to use AJAX to make a call to your server - that is exactly what @Adam Konieska has demonstrated in his answer. The server can then have a piece of PHP code to return the required data

Comment: Thanks shrmn. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get information from the database without reloading the page, you'd need to do an Ajax request to retrieve the information.

Something like this would work:

**PHP** - ajaxendpoint.php

```
<?php
    $d = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM canvas_data" );
    $usernames = array();
    while( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($d) ) { 
        $usernames[] = $r['name'];  
    }   
    echo json_encode( $usernames );
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getData() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);  //log the response from the database
            //if the PHP is returning a JSON object, you can parse that:
            var myArray = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }


    xhttp.open("GET", "ajaxendpoint.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**HTML** - index.html

```
<button onclick="getData()">
Load Data via Ajax
</button>
```

Here is another example Ajax request in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/77xynchz/1/

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to study this thoroughly. Just one more question. Where is the array stored now? The .responseText stays empty.

Comment: `response.text` is the string value returned by the ajax call, which is what is generated by the PHP.  If your PHP is written in a way that it returns an JSON object, you can use `JSON.parse()` to put the values into an array.  I updated the JS Fiddle and answer with an example.

Comment: Adam, it's working!!! Thank you so much!! This was bothering me for hoooouuurs. If you ever visit Amsterdam, I owe you a beer.

Comment: Ik ben blij dat het werkte. :-) Dank je wel!